# C# LINQ/EF throwing invalid cast on property with value conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

In my DB I have a table *Objects*:

```
   public class Objects {

        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        blah blah blah

        public JCal CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

The property *CreationDate* has a Value Converter, as below:

```
var stdJCalConversion = new ValueConverter<JCal, double>(
    v => v.Timestamp,
    v => new JCal(v));

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Objects>()
        .Property(e => e.CreationDate )
        .HasConversion(stdJCalConversion );
```

But when I try to run a simple where clause, like the following:

```
fetch = await Objects.Where(c => c.CreationDate > someDouble).ToListAsync();
```

I get the following exception: InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.Double' to 'x.Types.JCal'.

The struct that defines JCal has operator overloads to do comparisons between JCal and double types, but I suspect that LINQ can't work with the ValueConversions unlike EF. Is there any way to get this to work, or any workaround?

Comment: Can you make a static implicit operator?

Comment: in the JCal struct I have:
        `public static implicit operator double(JCal jcal)
            => jcal.Timestamp;

        public static implicit operator JCal(double timestamp)
            => new(timestamp);`

still getting the invalid cast exception though

Comment: EF knows nothing about your overloads for comparison. So it means that it cannot create SQL for your query.

Comment: Might be a far strech but in SQL you have [computed columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15) as well maybe this can perform the conversion from the date to the double and then you'll just have compare against the computed value. Definitely not an answer, but might be worth looking into

Comment: @JochemVanHespen not a perfect solution, but this is a good idea. I've created an _Timestamp record in the DB that evaluated to the regular Timestamp record (that in asp net is a JCal type) and that works. A bit more janky than I'd prefer, but it's better than nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use an expression, like so:

```
public static Expression<Func<Objects, bool>> IsHigherThanDouble(double someDouble)    
{        
   return (objects) => objects.CreationDate.Timestamp < someDouble;
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
fetch = await Objects.Where(IsHigherThanDouble(someDouble)).ToListAsync();
```